# jQuery hover effect on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to get a simple hover effect with jQuery on an image.
What I want to get eventually is a green hovering effect, with a text appearing along with the color. I don't know if I'm being clear.

For now, I just want the simple color hover effect to work.

Here is what I did first:

```
$("img").hover(
    function() {
        wid = $(this).width();
        hei = $(this).height();
        $("<div id='hover'></div>").insertBefore(this);
        $("#hover").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(60,147,138,0.2)",
            "width": wid,
            "height": hei,
            "z-index": "3",
            "position": "absolute"
        });
   },
   function() {
       $("#hover").remove();
   }
);
```

That code there is generating an empty div on top of my image with a transparent green background, to get that green hover effect. But it doesn't work great, and my guess is that the mouse is not on the image anymore, but on that div that has appeared just above it.

So I tried this then:

```
$("img").mouseenter(
    function() {
        wid = $(this).width();
        hei = $(this).height();
        $("<div id='hover'></div>").insertBefore(this);
        $("#hover").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(60,147,138,0.2)",
            "width": wid,
            "height": hei,
            "z-index": "3",
            "position": "absolute"
        });
    }
);

$("#hover").mouseleave(
    function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }
);
```

The hover effect is stable as I expected, but the mouseleave event just doesn't work.
I don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Oh, and here is [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Snowill/q5r3a00x/3/), just in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small digression first...
what you're trying to do can be easily done **using CSS only** and the `:hover` pseudo

```css
.imgWrapper,
.imgWrapper img{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.imgWrapper span{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
  background:rgba(60,147,138,0.2);
  padding:24px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size:2em;
}
.imgWrapper:hover span{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<span class="imgWrapper">
  <img src="http://lemagcinema.fr/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/alain_delon_59055-1024x768-500x372.jpg" width="300">
  <span>This is an<br>image caption!</span>
</span>
```

---

### To answer your jQuery question

```
$("#hover").mouseleave(
```

at the time you're assigning that function there's no `#hover` element on the page.

this would do it:

```
$("img").mouseenter(function() {

  var wid = $(this).width();
  var hei = $(this).height();

  $("<div id='hover' />").insertBefore(this);

  $("#hover").css({
    "background-color": "rgba(60,147,138,0.2)",
    "width": wid,
    "height": hei,
    "z-index": "3",
    "position": "absolute"
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

});
```

or even better you don't need the #ID at all: https://jsfiddle.net/q5r3a00x/5/

```
$("img").mouseenter(function() {

  var wid = $(this).width();
  var hei = $(this).height();

  $("<div />", {
    insertBefore : this,
    mouseout : function(){
      $(this).remove();
    },
    css : {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(60,147,138,0.2)",
      width: wid,
      height: hei,
      position: "absolute"
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Sir, I manly love you. Works perfectly fine now.
I was guessing I could do that with pure CSS, but I'm really not at ease with that at the time being.
Many thanks!

Comment: You can simply replace mouseenter and mouseleave with hover

Comment: @Snowill if you wrap your image into a SPAN element and immediately after the image you place an element overlay with the desired text... yes. CSS is quite enough.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'll try that as soon as I'm done with my project (school work, deadline in a few hours, many things left to do... you know). Thanks again :)

Comment: @Snowill no problem. Added an example to my answer that uses only CSS. Take a look and have fun. Good luck